# Vuejs Axios Upload file with params

Tags: api, vue.js, axios, form-data

[image]

i want upload file with API use vuejs & axios...  [i try code](https://gist.github.com/raisiqueira/49cf0646fc50da4370c54e1047a67dcd)

i get problems.. response require params gambar but this tutorial don't use params .... so im try try code but not working 
[image]

Comment: Replace image to text, please

Answer (score 0):

text parameter is added as well as a file

```
formData.append('fileKey', file);
formData.append('textKey', 'textValue');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.
let formData = new FormData();

```
for (let file of this.files) {
   formData.append("file", file);
   formData.append("judul", 'ayam');
 }
```